# Nomenclature of elsevier template

Tags: tables, align, article, nomenclature, nomencl

How do I add (Table 1:) before Nomenclature? I should look like (Table 1: Nomenclature).
I used the nomencl package.[image: Standard nomenclature is looked like]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which demonstrates how you are currently producing the nomenclature table. It's easier to provide accurate assistance in customising something when we can see how it's produced.